# VBA download a document from a public Google Drive address - .click event(?)

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

Update: it appears to needing a .click event, but unable to determine the correct syntax to use with the existing code.

Original Post:
I tried to adapt an existing stackoverflow answer code to my problem (as well as some other excel forum answers), but it has not resulted in the same solution. Any assistance would be appreciated.

I am trying to download a public file on a public google drive address. I am the owner of neither the doc or drive.

I have attempted using multiple file extensions, but when I used the html I noticed it was only taking the header, not the "container".

I am trying to grab the file in any format (docx, pdf, txt, csv)

Public File:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RaIps4g70ZWalb2UkLticEHM0OGcZF6h/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=111533769991350336043&rtpof=true&sd=true

or

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RaIps4g70ZWalb2UkLticEHM0OGcZF6h/edit

[vba](/questions/tagged/vba)

```
   Sub downloadFile()

      Const FOLDER = "C:\temp\"
    
      Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
      Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
      Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    
      If Not (fso.FolderExists(FOLDER)) Then MkDir FOLDER
    
      Dim oWinHttp As Object: Set oWinHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
      Dim oStream As Object: Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    
      Dim URL As String: URL = ws.Cells(2, 1).Value
      Dim ext As String: ext = ".docx"
    
      ' check folder exists
      If Not fso.FolderExists(FOLDER) Then
         MkDir FOLDER
      End If

        oWinHttp.Open "GET", URL, False
        oWinHttp.Send
        If oWinHttp.Status = 200 Then

            With oStream
                .Open
                .Type = 1
                .Write oWinHttp.ResponseBody
                .SaveToFile FOLDER & "File " & ext, 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
                .Close
            End With

            Else
                MsgBox URL, vbExclamation, "Status " & oWinHttp.Status
        End If
    
      MsgBox "File created", vbInformation

   End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code for each of the mentioned extensions? There is `FilePath` never declared nor being assigned to.

Comment: That was an artifact of the prior code, but didn't cause any issues. The macro runs and the Temp folder is populated with four files name "File" with extensions docx, pdf, excel csv, html

Comment: when I run the code `FilePath` is not declared and for ext = ".docx" ' Word found unreadable file  ext = ".pdf" Adobe reader found an unreadable file  but  ext = ".html" ' Firefox gives *The version of the browser you are using is no longer supported.* and the file is readable.  I suggest a change to WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 is needed to something more up to date.

Comment: Agree with your results, they are the same as my "File" output. But it reading the "site" not "downloading the file" -- It is not "downloading" from the drive. -- is there a "select menu option" that I can use to call the website menu "File" and "Download" ? <div id="docs-file-menu" role="menuitem" class="menu-button goog-control goog-inline-block" aria-disabled="false" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" style="user-select: none;">File</div>

Comment: on hoverover: <div id="docs-menubar" role="menubar" clase=""docs-menubar goog-container goog-container-horizontal" tabindex="0" style="user-select: none; max-width: 446px;" aria-activedescendant="bktxk3:ep">  -- I have downloaded data from <div> classes but not used a class as an action. The "bktxk3:ep" appears to be the unique identified for the docx download.

Comment: further down the rabbit hole, found a .click event, but not how to use it in conjunction with a filename and filepath for the output -- also many of the click event posts reference IE which is depreciated and would prefer a chrome solution for compatibility -- any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simpler alternative VBS can use sendkeys, it is second-best to a robotic browser approach like puppeteer, but often simple is fast enough to adjust.

Requirements are that Edge  (or chrome etc) is auto downloading to a fixed folder (here "downloads") because in this case there is unwanted confusion selecting "Save AS"

Launch browser from CMD line or via VBA shell command & trigger VBscript.

[image]

```
"%programfiles%\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --app=https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RaIps4g70ZWalb2UkLticEHM0OGcZF6h/edit
echo running script
timeout 8 && cscript savefiles.vbs
```

savefiles.vbs

```
' Edge is already open waiting for commands
 ' It is important that saving is to a fixed directory
 ' not open the "Where to save" dialog

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep(100)

' we need to use the app name  which is the TitleBar name
WshShell.AppActivate("01-1-2024 MONTHLY PRICE INDICES FOR ASPHALT CEMENT FOR ASPHALT CEMENT.docx")

' Type in ALT F to trigger File Menu actions set time gaps as required 1000=1second
WshShell.SendKeys "%F"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "%D"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "x"
WScript.Sleep(8000)
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "{ESC}"
' Add more user specific key ins e.g Opendocs
WshShell.SendKeys "%F"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "%D"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "o"
WScript.Sleep(8000)
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "{ESC}"
```

Comment: Much appreciated. I will have to see how this will fit into the current workflow, but it should solve the problem.